# Given a function, define an inverse function and show that it is well-defined...

Tags: real-analysis, functions

For my real analysis course, I have been tasked with proving that a function $f$ is a bijection if and only if it has an inverse. My instructor gave me a hint to start out with: "For the forward direction of the iff statement, define a candidate for the inverse function and show that it is well-defined."

Now, I know what it means for a function to be well-defined. There are some great definitions and examples on this website. However, every example I've seen that proves a function to be well-defined has been for a specific function, such as $f(x)=2x+7$ or something like that. All I have been given for my function is $f:A \rightarrow B$.

I've chosen my candidate for the inverse function: $g:B \rightarrow A$. Given that I have nothing specific to work with here, how do I actually show that this inverse function is well-defined? I feel like every attempt I've made so far has been me explaining what needs to be true to make the inverse function well-defined, as opposed to actually proving that it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is a bijection, $f$ is a surjection. For every $y \in B$, there is an $x \in A$ such that $f(x)=y$. Furthermore, it is also an injection, for every $y  \in B$, there is a unique $x \in A$, such that $f(x)=y$.

We define $g:B \to A, g(y)=x$  if $f(x)=y$.

Comment: Okay, so we have to use our knowledge of $f$ being bijective to help define $g$. Once we have $g$, how do we actually prove that $g$ is a bijection? I know what we would need to show to prove this, but I am unsure how to do so without making it look like a definition instead of a proof.

Comment: try to give it a try to show that it is injective and surjective. it doesn't matter what it looks like as long as it works. Hint: The reasoning is not "bijection" though.

Comment: I think that is the problem I am having though. When I try to show that it is injective and surjective, I feel like I am saying, "This is what should be true" instead of actually proving that it is.

Comment: Let's give it a try, suppose $g(y_1)=g(y_2)$ and $y_1 \ne y_2$. what contradiction do you get? Drawing pictures to get ideas might help. You can also write $g(y_1)=g(y_2)=x$ and write them in terms of $f$ to see clearer. Take your time.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. I'm sorry if my questions seem to have obvious answers, but I am really bad with proofs. They are extremely unintuitive to me, to the point where I don't know where to begin with most proofs, and I often can't tell when something has been proven. Consequently, real analysis is very difficult for me.

Comment: It is important to take time to learn. Give yourself a few hours and if you are really stuck, we can discuss. sketch stuff, get ideas. hint: review definition of functions. Over time, you will get better and also make more mistakes along the way.